# How to append settings from a a plugin

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a pretty basic app that uses plugins for most of the functionality. I want to allow each plugin to define some custom menus and menu items, gather all these menus in one place (maybe AppController::initialize), and create an array that will be passed to a main-menu.php Element that will render the complete menu.

What I've done so far is define the menus in the plugin

```
# plugins/TestPlugin/config/menus.php

return [
    'menus' => [
        [
            'header' => 'TestPlugin',
            [
                'title' => 'Click me!',
                'href' => './',
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Click me too!',
                'href' => './',
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Load the config:

```
# plugins/TestPlugin/config/bootstrap.php

use Cake\Core\Configure;
Configure::load('TestPlugin.menus', 'default' , true);
```

And read the variable:

```
# src/Controller/AppController.php

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $plugin_menus = Configure::read('menus);
```

But if I have more that one plugins, `menus` is being overwritten.

I'm not sure if that's the best way. What I try to achieve is having multiple modules change (append to) the same config variable

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would use a [View Cell](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html) which generates the navigation.

Inside each plugins `bootstrap.php` file I'd have the plugin append to a `Configure` variable to add it's navigation.

```php
Configure::write('navigation', array_merge(Configure::read('navigation'), $myNavArray);
```

Then in the Navigation View Cell, I could just process that `Configure` variable.

```php
foreach (Configure::read('navigation') as $navItem) {
    // Build nav, or output, etc
}
```

The advantages to this are that your navigation will be the same everywhere, due to the View Cell. You'll also have a View Cell controller, meaning you can do more stuff to the navigation such as checking permissions before outputting navigation items for example.

By hooking the bootstrap, you've also got the flexibility to include or not include plugins navigation by just either not loading the bootstrap, ot checking the plugins setup first.

Comment: My problem is that I load the plugin's navigation with `Configure::read('menus);` which will overwrite any other plugin's `$menu` variable. So I am looking for a way to load the `plugins/TestPlugin/menus.php` file that returns a `$menus` array, without overwriting any already existing `$menus` variable.

Comment: You've missed my use of `array_merge` in the answer. So that you can key the array in a multi dimensional way to accomodate your extra navigation data.